# is in comparision with pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, comparison, series

I have a string variable (sample_id) and am trying to see this element exists in a pandas series.

For example:

```
sample_id = "HERUSAF000043287899"
```

and

```
>>> failed.ID
5      HERUSAF000043287899
175    HERUSAM000043667608
195    HERUSAM000043667594
212    HERUSAF000043733959
213    HERUSAF000043733954
214    HERUSAM000043600074
215    HERUSAF000043733999
216    HERUSAF000043733982
217    HERUSAF000043733983
220    HERUSAM000043733661
221    HERUSAM000043734015
222    HERUSAM000043631768
223    HERUSAM000043733650
224    HERUSAM000043733649
225    HERUSAM000043733665
227    HERUSAM000043734019
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Yet, when I do a comparison:

```
>>> sample_id in failed.ID
False
```

But, if I compare the values individually, the comparison works:

```
>>> sample_id == failed.ID.iloc[0]
True
```

How can I check for the individual value in the series without making individual checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `in` operator checks the `pandas` index. Check the values explicitely:

```
sample_id in failed.ID.values
```

Comment: @CarrieBrown No problem. If you think this answers the question, you can accept the answer using the checkmark  - and I would appreciate an upvote too :)

Comment: Will do, just waiting out the timer before I can accept :)

Comment: I'd appreciate understanding why this answer was downvoted... whoever you are.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the handy series method `isin`.

```
 failed.ID.isin([ sample_id])
```

Comment: I pursued this avenue, but the return wasn't quite what I was looking for (returns a series as opposed to a single boolean)